# Leaflet sidebar v2 pushes zoombox too far over

Tags: zooming, leaflet, sidebar

I am using the Leaflet plugin [Sidebar v2](https://github.com/Turbo87/sidebar-v2) for a resource map I've created. However, even when minimized it permanently pushes the zoombox controls over to the position it's in when the sidebar is activated.

How can I get the zoombox to push right back to it's normal position when the sidebar is minimized?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The plugin is changing css for .leaflet-left (https://github.com/Turbo87/sidebar-v2/blob/gh-pages/scss/leaflet-sidebar.scss#L31)

When sidebar is minimized, you have to set .leaflet-left to its initial value

```
.leaflet-left {
left: 0;
}
```

How you will do that depends on your implementation. You could show a JSFiddle example of how code looks like at the moment